# Turn camera flash LED on/off with SL4A Python

Tags: android, python, sl4a

How can I turn the camera LED on and off with sl4a Python? Maximum intensity is ok.

Anything in android.* ?

Here's the code:

```
import sys

def toggle_LED(action="on"):
    if action == 'on':
        with open('/sys/class/leds/torch-flash/flash_light', 'w') as on:
            on.write('1')
    elif action == 'off':
        with open('/sys/class/leds/torch-flash/flash_light', 'w') as off:
            off.write('0')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    toggle_LED()
    while True:
        if strip(sys.stdin.read())[0] == 'q':
            toggle_LED(action='off')
            sys.exit()
```

EDIT: The phone is a Huawei Ideos X5 U8800H

Comment: Really? A down vote? Reaaally??

@ShivanRaptor I have tried writing a zero or a one to the file `/sys/class/leds/torch-flash/flash_light` but the folder `torch-flash` is missing on my phone. So i'm looking for an API call that works on any phone.

Comment: it's not me to downvote. calm down sir. please provide your codes.

Answer (score 2):

> Anything in android.* ?

You can turn on and off flashlight in following manner in Android.

Turn on the flashlight.

```
Camera cam = null;
public void turnOnFlashLight() {
    try {
        if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
            cam = Camera.open();
            Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            cam.setParameters(p);
            cam.startPreview();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception throws in turning on flashlight.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Turn off the flashlight.

```
public void turnOffFlashLight() {
    try {
        if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
            cam.stopPreview();
            cam.release();
            cam = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception throws in turning off flashlight.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Do not forgot to add permission in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
```

For more reference: [Turn on and turn off flash light programmatically in Android](http://acomputerengineer.wordpress.com/2013/09/12/turn-on-and-turn-off-flash-light-programmatically-in-android/)

Comment: That is in **java**. I need to do it in **Python** via SL4A.

Comment: @TimothyMakobu: Yes, but I post answer for Android as you ask for **Anything in android?**. I don't know how to do it in Python.

Comment: I meant `android.*` as in the main package in SL4A Python for accessing the API.

Comment: @TimothyMakobu: Sorry, I misunderstood it.